# How to join two dataframes with different key column names in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a X dataframe as,

```
DT_X = dt.Frame({
    
    'date':['2020-09-01','2020-09-02','2020-09-03'],
    'temp':[35.3,32.9,43.2]
    
})
```

```
Out[4]: 
   | date        temp
-- + ----------  ----
 0 | 2020-09-01  35.3
 1 | 2020-09-02  32.9
 2 | 2020-09-03  43.2

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Another dataframe Y as,

```
DT_Y = dt.Frame({
    
    'stop_date' : ['2020-08-01','2020-09-01','2020-09-03','2020-09-07'],
    'is_arrested':[True,False,False,True]
    
})
```

```
Out[6]: 
   | stop_date   is_arrested
-- + ----------  -----------
 0 | 2020-08-01            1
 1 | 2020-09-01            0
 2 | 2020-09-03            0
 3 | 2020-09-07            1

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now I would like to perform JOIN operation on X and Y, for that i'm supposed to assign a key on X dataframe as,

```
DT_X.key='date'
```

```
Out[8]: 
date       | temp
---------- + ----
2020-09-01 | 35.3
2020-09-02 | 32.9
2020-09-03 | 43.2

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Next I'm joining X and Y as ,

```
DT_Y[:,:,join(DT_X)]
```

Here it is throwing out an error as ,

```
In [9]: DT_Y[:,:,join(DT_X)]                                                                                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a3bc1690fb98> in <module>
----> 1 DT_Y[:,:,join(DT_X)]

ValueError: Key column `date` does not exist in the left Frame
```

Of course **date** is not existed in DT_Y, it has a column name as **stop_date**.

**How to perform join operations in this scenario** ?? i.e **No match of column names.**

**Note** :

An work around for this is to change the column name of DT_Y as

```
DT_Y.names = {'stop_date':'date'}
```

```
DT_Y[:,:,join(DT_X)]
```

The joined DT can be viewed as,

```
Out[11]: 
   | date        is_arrested  temp
-- + ----------  -----------  ----
 0 | 2020-08-01            1  NA  
 1 | 2020-09-01            0  35.3
 2 | 2020-09-03            0  43.2
 3 | 2020-09-07            1  NA  

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here is the expected output:

```
Out[13]: 
   | stop_date   is_arrested  temp
-- + ----------  -----------  ----
 0 | 2020-08-01            1  NA  
 1 | 2020-09-01            0  35.3
 2 | 2020-09-03            0  43.2
 3 | 2020-09-07            1  NA  

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: so what's the problem with changing the column name?

Comment: DT_Y : stop_date column says: when an activity is done , where as DT_X: date says what day is it. so if DT_Y column name changed to date it won't make sense further analysis. i hope you understand my point.

Comment: ah is it changed completely? I thought it gives some kind of an alias to column

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia can you post the expected output? Also, at the moment, joins in pydatatable is not robust.

Comment: @sammywemmy i just added the expected output in the question itself.

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia, i think the only option is to rename it after the join. Not sure if there is any other way at the moment.

Comment: @sammywemmy Yes agreed. for now i can go with it. i guess it would be a feature request as well. let us discuss it with h2o's team if OK.

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia, it is already listed on possible APIs for version 0.11 release. However, I believe if more people show an interest in it, it will be worked on. So, please go ahead and make a comment on the github issues page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `join()` only supports the same column names in the both frames, please refer to [documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/join.html) for more details. However, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1080) to improve the join functionality/API.

Meanwhile, if you prefer not to rename the columns you can do the following

```
DT_Y_date = DT_Y[:, {"date":f[0], "is_arrested":f[1]}]
DT_YX_joined = DT_Y_date[:, :, join(DT_X)]
```

Then, `DT_YX_joined` will have the data you are looking for

```
   | date        is_arrested  temp
-- + ----------  -----------  ----
 0 | 2020-08-01            1  NA  
 1 | 2020-09-01            0  35.3
 2 | 2020-09-03            0  43.2
 3 | 2020-09-07            1  NA
```

You can even do a one-liner like

```
DT_YX_joined = DT_Y[:, {"date":f[0], "is_arrested":f[1]}][:, :, join(DT_X)]
```

but it may not be readable enough. Also note, that no data copies are created here, it is only the column name that changes.